# why does getDay() return the wrong day of the week?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have the following line of code in vueJS which should return the day of the week into this.day, however it returns the wrong day of the week. It shows Thursday when today is Friday. The rest of the variables all return correctly however:

```js
callFunction: function () {                  
            this.date = new Date().getDate();           
            this.day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { weekday: 'long'}).format(new Date().getDay());
            var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
            this.month = months[new Date().getMonth()];
        },
```

Comment: getDay() returns the day of the week based on 0 = Sunday, 1= Monday.

Comment: Days counts from 0, not from 1

Comment: The [`.format()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format) method of `DateTimeFormat` expects a `Date` object and not a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in specs, `getDay()` returns [a number between 0-6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) (sunday - saturday).

In your case, I would just use a full `Date` object, instead of returning whatever `Date.getDay()` returns.

```
this.day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { weekday: 'long'}).format(new Date()); // Friday
```

Comment: _"I would just use a full Date object"_ - You should replace _"I would..._ with _"You have to..."_ because that's how `.format()` is specified: `Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.format(date)` - It's only parameter has to be a `Date` object#

Comment: @Andreas: It is also possible to pass ticks.

Comment: @JavaScript Yes (because of [13.1.5.4a](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-datetime-format-functions): `Let x be ? ToNumber(date).`) but the call of `ToNumber()` and the name of the parameter suggests that it should be a `Date` object. So just use it like it should be used ;)

Comment: @Andreas: Doesnt change that your comment is inaccurate.